# Is it possible to time synchronize two topics in ROS of same message type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, rospy

I try to map robot gripper position to the resistance exerted by the object held by the gripper. I subscribed the gripper position from one topic and resistance value from another topic, since I want to ensure that the gripper position corresponds to the exact resistance value at that position. Given that both are float messages, how can I synchronize them?

```
self.sub1 = rospy.Subscriber("resistance", Float64, self.ard_callback)
self.sub2 = rospy.Subscriber("gripperpos", Float64, self.grip_callback)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `TimeSynchronizer` in `rospy`.

This is an example of subscribing multiple topics to get data at the same time:

```
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo

def callback(image, camera_info):
  # Solve all of perceptions here...

image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('image', Image)
info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('camera_info', CameraInfo)

ts = message_filters.TimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub], 10)
ts.registerCallback(callback)
rospy.spin()
```

---

If your problem was not resolved, use `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` rather than `TimeSynchronizer`:

```
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub], 1, 1)
```

---

[Read More](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters)