# How to subscribe to two image topics in ROS using Python

Tags: python, callback, ros

I am trying to read left and right camera images from a vehicle to do some image processing. I am unsure of how to use the same callback function to process each image. I have seen [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458218/is-it-possible-to-time-synchronize-two-topics-in-ros-of-same-message-type) where the data type was different, but not where both are of the same type, such as images. [In this example](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/how-to-get-a-python-node-in-ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics), separate callbacks were used.

Here is my current attempt:

```
import rospy
import cv2
import os
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import message_filters

def read_cameras():
    imageL = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/left/image_raw", Image, image_callback)
    imageR = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/right/image_raw", Image, image_callback)
    # Synch images here ? 
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([imageL, imageR], 10)
    rospy.spin()
    
def image_callback(imageL, imageR):
    br = CvBridge()
    rospy.loginfo("receiving frame")
    imageLeft = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(imageL)
    imageRight = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(imageR)
    # Do some fancy computations on each image
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        read_cameras()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Additionaly, even after reading the [documentation on approximate time synchronization](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime), I still don't understand the parameters I need to input. Each camera should be outputting images at 24fps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each node needs to initialize itself first before it can interact with the ROS network using `rospy.init_node()`.

Also, you need to provide two `message_filter.Subscriber` instead of `rospy.Subscriber` to the `message_filter.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer`.
Finally, instead of setting the callback for each subscriber you should set it once for the `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` using `registerCallback`.

Here is a working example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import rospy
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import message_filters

def read_cameras():
    imageL = message_filters.Subscriber("/camera/left/image_raw", Image)
    imageR = message_filters.Subscriber("/camera/right/image_raw", Image)

    # Synchronize images
    ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([imageL, imageR], queue_size=10, slop=0.5)
    ts.registerCallback(image_callback)
    rospy.spin()

def image_callback(imageL, imageR):
    br = CvBridge()
    rospy.loginfo("receiving frame")
    imageLeft = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(imageL)
    imageRight = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(imageR)
    # Process images...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_node')
    try:
        read_cameras()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Be sure to check the delay (`slop`) for your `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` and set it according to your data.