# Synchronizing multiple topic subscriptions in ROS when using pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, ros, qthread

I found a method from this discussion [How to subscribe to two image topics in ROS using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729615/how-to-subscribe-to-two-image-topics-in-ros-using-python) and I did more research on that method using the official documentation on how to synchronize multiple topic subscriptions https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy. And I tried to use it when I am developing a GUI to show some details on top of ROS. For that I had to use QThread in pyqt5 and Here's how I did it.

```
class QNode_upgraded1(QThread):
    rosShutdown = pyqtSignal() ## signal the gui for a shutdown
    def __init__(self, queue_total):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        rospy.init_node('listenerim',anonymous=True)

        self.queue = queue_total
        self.dic = {'img':None, 'msg':None, 'img_count':0, 'msg_count':0}
        #self.model = QStringListModel(self)
        #self.list = []
        #self.model.setStringList(self.list)
        #self.text_window.setModel(self.model)

        ##connect signal
    def __del__(self):
        if not rospy.is_shutdown():

            #rospy.shutdown('shutdown reason')
            self.wait()

    def callback(self, data_img, data_msg):
        br = CvBridge()
        #rospy.loginfo('receiving image')
        dx = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(data_img)
        self.dic["img"] = dx
        self.dic['img_count'] += 1
        #self.queue.put(frame)

    
        if data_msg.data != 'None':           
            self.dic['msg'] = 'None'   
        else:
            self.dic['msg'] = data_msg.data
        self.dic['msg_count'] += 1
        if max(self.dic['img_count'], self.dic['msg_count']) > 1000:
            self.dic['img_count'] = 0
            self.dic['msg_count'] = 0
        self.queue.put(self.dic)

    def run(self):
        img_=message_filters.Subscriber('/reolink/image_raw', Image) #2hz
        msg_=message_filters.Subscriber('/reolink/periodic_msg', String)
        #sync topic subscriptions
        ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([img_,msg_], queue_size=10, slop=0.5, allow_headerless=True)
        ts.registerCallback(self.callback)

        rospy.spin()
        self.rosShutdown.emit() #emit signal for shutdown
```

But when I did this it did not subscribed to multiple topics. But when I use two callback methods to subscribe two topics seperately, it worked. But the topic subscriptions are not synchronized.

```
class QNode_upgraded(QThread):
    rosShutdown = pyqtSignal() ## signal the gui for a shutdown
    def __init__(self, queue_total):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        rospy.init_node('listenerim',anonymous=True)

        self.queue = queue_total
        self.dic = {'img':None, 'msg':None, 'img_count':0, 'msg_count':0}

        ##connect signal
    def __del__(self):
        if not rospy.is_shutdown():

            #rospy.shutdown('shutdown reason')
            self.wait()

    def callback1(self, data):
        br = CvBridge()
        #rospy.loginfo('receiving image')
        dx = br.imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
        self.dic["img"] = dx
        self.dic['img_count'] += 1
        #self.queue.put(frame)

    def callback2(self, msg_data):
        if msg_data.data != 'None':
            self.dic['msg'] = 'None'
        else:
            self.dic['msg'] = msg_data.data
        self.dic['msg_count'] += 1
        if max(self.dic['img_count'], self.dic['msg_count']) > 1000:
            self.dic['img_count'] = 0
            self.dic['msg_count'] = 0
        self.queue.put(self.dic)

    def run(self):
        rospy.Subscriber('/reolink/image_raw', Image, self.callback1) #2hz
        rospy.Subscriber('/reolink/periodic_msg', String, self.callback2)
        rospy.spin()
        self.rosShutdown.emit() #emit signal for shutdown
```

For further clarification what I try to do here is subscribing two topics and the subscribed data is put into a dictionary and they are appended to a python queue, so that I can use it in main program. Can someone point out why the first method is not working and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: I think the != is wrong here: `if data_msg.data != 'None': `

Comment: Actually 'None' is just a string. Not a None object in python. sorry my bad.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the != logic, because the next statement pretty much ignores any msg except for 'None'. 
If the answer answers your qn, pls accept it, or if its insufficient, feel free to ask or clarify.

Comment: yeah, the answer helped me to identify why the topic subscriptions were not synced in code 2. I made it work. But I couldn't code 1 get to work. still searching for it.

Comment: If you at least have the data coming in on regular subscribers, and you know their frequency, you could also do your own "syncing" to whichever level you're comfortable with in your own code. Either use each separate callback to store a global array (latest 1 or latest N, whichever is more helpful/correct) of the last few, then have a periodic timer running, or pick one of the callbacks, and output on that. Perhaps you only need to tie the msg to the latest img? So save the latest img, and every new msg, run all your simultaneous callbacks? Or something like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw it out there, your first code looks pretty close to right, and if your second is receiving data, then it might be in the tuning / frequencies.
For example, if they're not close enough in occurrence, then the approximate time won't pick them up. Here's a few ways you can check what your timings are.

1. `ros topic hz`: While running your sensor, use this to see what rates your topics are actually coming out at; if they're too far apart, then they'll only alias some of the time.
2. In your second set of code, publish the receive times. `rospy.get_time()` can get you the current time, and if you save the times for each callback in a global variable, you can print out the deltas between them everytime one of them gets updated (for precise logging... just not too much).
3. Run the first set of code, again, but instead of using your real sensor to source data, have a second node that publishes an empty Image/String pair to those topics, at the exact same time. If that works, then your code (if aligned enough) definitely should work.
4. Or try increasing the cue and slop a lot. Not ideal, but it could give you an idea of what's happening, if they're only coinciding rarely.